# Parsley.js, compare text fields values

Tags: javascript, parsley.js, parsley

Using *parsley js*, I would like to test if `password` and `password_confirmation` fields both match, but so far my below code fails.

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
   <i class="material-icons prefix">security</i>
   <input id="pw" type="password"name="password"  class="validate" required="" minlength="8" data-parsley-equalto="#pw1">
   <label for="icon_prefix" >Mot de passe</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">security</i>
    <input  **id="pw1"** type="password" name="password"  class="validate" required="" minlength="8"data-parsley-equalto="#pw">
    <label for="icon_prefix">Confirmer</label>
```

Comment: Try using just one `equalto`.

Comment: Formatted code and rephrased a little bit.

Comment: I tried also one " equalto" but still doesn't work